# textarea val() edit and remove string with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i'm creating a link sharing that on bind() events of a specific textarea ( where i paste links ) it does an `$.post` ajax callback with a preview (in case of youtube or vimeo link).
Basically, i would remove link into textarea each times that link is detected and preview is gotten.

this is the function that does the callback :

```
    $('#writer').bind('change keypress keyup keydown',function() {

   var value_= $('#writer').val();
            $('#thumb-temp').hide();


            $.post( 'checklink.php?', { string : value_ }, 
            function(response) {
                $('.writer').prepend(response);
                $('#thumb-temp').show();

    }).fail(function() { alert( "error" ) })
});
```

and the page **checklink.php** that should remove the link

```
<?
    $link = $_POST['string'];

            $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
            preg_match($reg_exUrl, $link, $url);

            $link = $url[0];
?>
<script>clearTextarea('<? echo $link ?>')</script>
```

and in the end the clearTextarea() function

```
function clearTextarea(url) {
var _textarea = $('#writer');
var _curVal     =   _textarea.val();
        var _curUrl =   url;
        var _regex      =   new RegExp( _curUrl , 'g' );
        var _newVal     =   _curVal.replace( _regex , '' );

        _textarea.val( _newVal );
}
```

Now, apparentely, this should works but nothing happens, any ideas ? I do not understand where I'm wrong :(

Comment: Jsfiddle would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can run javascript that way (echoing from PHP). I would call it from the  $.post directly.

Comment: You can, but it would have to be requested using the "script" datatype and the script tags would have to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I will suggest you not to send the ajax so many times. 
Regex is basically what you can do in JS as well. So instead of sending ajax - check for links in your JS code.
Second, if you want to change the value of textarea, you should use `html()` instead of `val()`.

Answer (score 0):

The Order should be,

```
  <script type="text/javascript">       

        function clearTextarea(url) { 
                var _textarea = $('#writer');
                var _curVal     =   _textarea.val();
                        var _curUrl =   url;
                        var _regex      =   new RegExp( _curUrl , 'g' );
                        var _newVal     =   _curVal.replace( _regex , '' );

                 _textarea.val( url );
        }
    </script>
```

Textarea in HTML:

```
  <textarea id="writer"></textarea>
```

PHP code

```
          <?php
             $link = $_POST['string'];

            $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
            preg_match($reg_exUrl, $link, $url);

            $link = $url[0];

        ?>
```

Calling clearTextarea function();

```
   <script>clearTextarea('<?php echo $link ?>');</script>
```

Comment: Due to the Loading behaviour, you are calling clearTextarea function before it gets loaded, thats why

Answer (score 0):

i solved in this way

```
function clearTextarea() {
        var _textarea = $('#writer');
        var _curVal     =   _textarea.val();
        var _curUrl     =   _curVal.match(/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/gi);

        var _newVal     =   _curVal.replace( _curUrl , '' );

        _textarea.val(_newVal);
}
```

and call clearTextarea() on ajax complete.
That's it ;D